# how to add a static text on the blog list page of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

so, i created a child theme from oceanWP.

i decided to add in my functions.php.....

```
function echo_comment_id( $comment_id ) {
    if ( is_home() ){
        $content = 'hi there';
        echo $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_action( 'the_content', 'echo_comment_id', 10, 1 );
```

my 'hi there' prints out twice though...... cause of the echo.
without the echo, nothing prints out.

im thinking it gets hidden or immediately goes away?

Comment: You can use wordpress is_page() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wpbf_main_content_open` is not a native Wordpress hook, it seems to be a hook from the Page Builder Framework. Do you use the Page Builder Framework?

However, that what you want can be done with native functions.

Action Hook [loop_start](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/loop_start/)

```
// place this in your functions.php
add_action( 'loop_start', 'add_static_text_on_blog_list_page' );

function add_static_text_on_blog_list_page(  ) {

    // Check if this is the Blog-Post-Page and main query.
    if ( is_home() && is_main_query() ) {
        echo '<h1>Hey everyone!</h1><p>This is a quick intro.</p>';
    }

}
```

Another way is the [Custom Blog Posts Index Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-front-page-templates/#custom-blog-posts-index-page-template). Make a copy from the `page.php` (or `home.php` if exists in the Parent-Theme) and save it as `home.php` in your Child-Theme. Then you can add the static text to this template (before the lopp starts).

Comment: hmmm still not showing up when i add that function......

good catch on wpbf_main_content_open. i didn't know it wasnt native.

do you think i need to add echo?

Comment: dang it. i added the custom blog posts page. but it displays all my entries.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now it should work for you.

Comment: may i ask one last thing? right now, the text is appearing in my header, and also underneath my page title.

appearing under my page title is ideal. but its weird for it to appear in the header section where my logo is

Comment: If you want to add text in the header, you can to this in the `header.php` directly (in your child-theme copy). Use condition `is_home()` to add the text just to on blog list page.

Comment: oh i think you misread it. i dont want it in my header. but its showing in both my header and underneath the page title right now.

Comment: Woot? This sounds strange to me. Your choosen Theme must use the loop in the header too. In this case i recommend to use `home.php` in your child theme and add the text there.